# Twitter Bootstrap: Stacking Navigation on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, uinavigationbar

I am trying to have a very simple navigation bar in my twitter boostrap template that will simply stack the menu items vertically on mobile (and show children when tapped). Since I'm a newbie at Bootstrap (I'm used to Foundation 3) I used the [Cyborg colorscheme](http://bootswatch.com/cyborg/) from Bootswatch to jumpstart my development of this site. I have included all the javascript plugins available and jquery in the header.

I am thus far extremely confused by the documentation and would greatly appreciate some help modifying the current menu to function properly on mobile. Thank you!

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As an example of what I am trying to accomplish and have done so with Foundation 3, please visit [www.asiantowncenter.com](http://www.asiantowncenter.com)

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to do something similar to the Cyborg menu that has 'Typography, Navbar, Buttons, Forms ....' ?

Answer (score 0):

To have the value collapse you need to add a `.nav-collapse` div to your `navbar-inner` and set it to target your collapsable div navigation section.

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
    <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <!--These are to make the button look fancy-->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>

    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

More info in the [Responsive Section](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) of the bootstrap documentation